# display value of pointer after function alter with array C

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

When i run this it gives a string of numbers and letters (an address im guessing) where have i gone wrong? I im trying to display the highest and lowest numbers

intArray is a 1d array of 10 numbers and size = 10

```
void greatAndSmall(int intsAray[], const int SZ, int greatAdd, int smallAdd)        //def func
{

    while (x < SZ)
    {
        if (intsAray[x] > greatAdd)
            greatAdd = intsAray[x];
        else
            break;
        if (intsAray[x] < smallAdd)
            smallAdd = intsAray[x];
        else
            break;
        x = x + 1;
    }
}

greatAndSmall(intArray, SIZE, &great, &small);      //IN MAIN FUNC
    cout << "The smallest of these numbers is: " << small << "\n";  //display smallest
    cout << "The largest of these numbers is: " << great;       //display greatest
```

Comment: This can't possibly compile. `x` is not declared; `&great` and `&small1` are pointers but the function expects parameters of type `int`. Show your real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, as written, is not valid C/C++ and won't compile. It also has logical problems and won't work even if it would compile (the `break`s you are using are completely redundant.)

Just use this code:

```
void greatAndSmall (int intsArray [], int sz, int * largest, int * smallest)
{
    if (sz < 1) return;
    *largest = *smallest = intsArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < sz; ++i)
    {
        if (intsArray[i] > *largest) *largest = intsArray[i];
        if (intsArray[i] < *smallest) *smallest = intsArray[i];
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: This is C code. Do not for one second think that, just because you use `cout`, this can be counted as C++ code.

Just for comparison, this is how one might write this in C++:

```
// Largest value in first and smallest value in second
std::pair<int, int> greatAndSmall (std::vector<int> const & c)
{
    if (c.empty()) return {};
    std::pair<int, int> ret (c[0], c[0]);
    for (unsigned i = 1; i < c.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (c[i] > ret.first) ret.first = c[i];
        if (c[i] < ret.second) ret.second = c[i];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

or this more general (and admittedly more complex) version:

```
template<typename C>
auto greatAndSmall (C const & c)
    -> std::pair<typename C::value_type, typename C::value_type>
{
    if (c.empty()) return {};
    auto ret = std::make_pair(*c.begin(), *c.begin());
    for (auto const & v : c)
    {
        if (v > ret.first) ret.first = v;
        if (v < ret.second) ret.second = v;
    }
    return ret;
}
```